# flatten ansible result using jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am getting a list of elements of the same structure using ansible, it looks a bit like the following:

```
results: [
  {
    "a": "foo",
    "b": "bar",
    "c": [
      {"c1": ...},
      {"c2": ...}
      {"c3": ...}]
  },
  {
    "a": "foo2",
    "b": "bar2",
    "c": [
      {"c4": ...},
      {"c5": ...}
      {"c6": ...}]
  }
]
```

I would need to iterate over all subelements of c - of all elements, so what I want is a list of the elements: c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6...

Normally I would use a nested loop, but since ansible is using jinja2s filters, I have no clue on how to accomplish that. I am totally new to this kind of data transformation.

---

To give some context, the actual code is:

```
- name: Find log files that are older than 1 day
  find:
    paths: "{{ item }}"
    age: 1d
    recurse: no
  register: oldLogs
  loop:
    - "/var/log"
    - "/home/user/log"

- name: print files
  debug:
    msg: "{{ oldLogs.results | <some filters here> }}\n"
```

Yes, I know I could pass a list of paths to find instead, but that's not the way I want to go, instead I would like to learn on how to use filters in such a situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example,

```yaml
results_c: "{{ (results|
                map(attribute='c')|
                flatten|
                combine).keys()|list }}"
```

gives the list

```yaml
results_c: [c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    results:
      - a: foo
        b: bar
        c:
          - c1: val_1
          - c2: val_2
          - c3: val_3
      - a: foo2
        b: bar2
        c:
          - c4: val_4
          - c5: val_5
          - c6: val_6
    results_c: "{{ (results|
                    map(attribute='c')|
                    flatten|
                    combine).keys()|list }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ results_c }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=c1) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: c1
ok: [localhost] => (item=c2) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: c2
ok: [localhost] => (item=c3) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: c3
ok: [localhost] => (item=c4) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: c4
ok: [localhost] => (item=c5) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: c5
ok: [localhost] => (item=c6) => 
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: c6
```

Comment: Hui, could you maybe explain your solution a little bit more in depth? Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Take the expression `results_c` and feel free to display the intermediate results of the filters in the pipe step by step. First, you'll see the list of the attributes `c`. This list will be flattened in the next step, and finally, in the pipe, the dictionaries will be combined. As the last step, you get the dictionary keys. You're welcome!